# In excel, is there a way to program "Refresh All" button so that it loads Queries in batch at a time?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have ~150 Queries in a Microsoft Excel file. Clicking "Refresh all" would freeze my PC and resulted in some of the data not being able to load correctly even though network connection is good.

I'm looking to find a way to program "Refresh All" button so that it load maybe 5 to 10 queries at a time then move on the the next. I tried that manually and it loads without any problem. Just 150 queries at a time is too much.

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any simple way of resolving your query, but I have some thougts of a kind of a workaround. Below you can find two VBA macros that may help you a bit. The first code lists all queries that you have in your workbook in a new tab:

```
Sub ListQueries()
    'Add tab to list all queries
    Dim wsQueries As Worksheet
    Set wsQueries = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    wsQueries.Name = "Query list"
    wsQueries.Range("a1").Value = "Query name"
    Dim con As WorkbookConnection
    For Each con In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        If UCase(Left(con.Name, 8)) = "QUERY - " Then wsQueries.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = con.Name
    Next con
End Sub
```

When it is finished you can use the second one. This time it will loop through all queries and refresh them but only as many as you will define in this clause `If counter = 10 Then Exit For` - if you want 15 then feel free to amend it. For each refereshed query it will add 'Yes' in column B. When you run RefreshQueries it at first checks whether a query is marked as 'Yes' and omit it if it's true.

```
Sub RefreshQueries()
    Dim counter As Byte
    counter = 0
    'Range with query names
    Dim rQueries As Range
    Dim rQuery As Range
    Dim wsQueries As Worksheet
    Set wsQueries = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Query list")
    Set rQueries = wsQueries.Range("a2:a" & wsQueries.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    wsQueries.Range("b1") = "Refreshed"
    For Each rQuery In rQueries
        If counter = 10 Then Exit For 'if more than 10 queries refreshed then exit loop
        'If query is refreshed then omit it and go to next
        If rQuery.Offset(0, 1) <> "Yes" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Connections(rQuery.Value).Refresh
            rQuery.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes"
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next rQuery
End Sub
```

To sum up, you should run ListQueries once and RefreshQueries as many times as required to refresh all of them.

Comment: Exactly what my thinking is. Where do I input those two code? I am using Excel and "Queries & Connection" is a button under "Data" tab.

Comment: The code works so thank you for converting my idea into code. However the problem I have was when it loads 10 queries at a time none of them was loadable. I used "Refresh All" button and it loads about 30% successfully. So I guess my idea to load 10 at a time is not a good one...

Comment: I think that the issue might be also with query dependencies. If you refresh a query that referrs somehow to another one (merge, append, filter, etc.), it is required to refresh all of them at this point. So even if the macro refreshes 10 queries they migh be connected with another 100. You can check dependencies is power query editor->View->Query dependencies.

Comment: All of my queries are independent. On another hand, I have another file with 70 queries, loading from same website, same data type, no merge, append or filter applied (just different url) and it takes about a minute to finish "Refresh All" (only about 5 queries out of 70 are not loadable so I just refresh them manually).

Comment: I checked query dependencies: each queries come directly from source and they are not linked together.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you share the file? I don't have any other idea at the moment. Maybe if I see the file, I will notice something.

Comment: I can't share the file. My next approach is to divide the data set into 2 part, first is live data (only a part of the table in my queries) which I can load at any moment during the day and second is data I can load individually at the end of the day (this set is "heavier data"). I can't think of a better way to proceed yet so I will try that today and let you know the result.